# How to split work over multiple cores/processors

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I want to create a small test that carries out some calculations to see how fast a processor will finish it in.  For example I want to get the CPU info of a machine and then run a test like so:

```
public static double SumRootN(int root)
    {
        double result = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            result += Math.Exp(Math.Log(i) / root);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labelPhysicalProcessors.Text = "";
        labelProcessorName.Text = "";
        labelLogicalProcessors.Text = "";
        labelCores.Text = "";

        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        string physicalProcessors = String.Empty;
        string processorName = String.Empty;
        string logicalProcessors = String.Empty;
        string coreCount = String.Empty;

        foreach (var item in new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem").Get())
        {
            physicalProcessors = item["NumberOfProcessors"].ToString();
            logicalProcessors = item["NumberOfLogicalProcessors"].ToString();
        }


        foreach (var item in new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Processor").Get())
        {
            coreCount = item["NumberOfCores"].ToString();
            processorName = item["Name"].ToString();
        }

        labelPhysicalProcessors.Text = physicalProcessors;
        labelProcessorName.Text = processorName;
        labelLogicalProcessors.Text = logicalProcessors;
        labelCores.Text = coreCount;

        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();


        Parallel.For(2, 20, (i) =>
        {
            var result = SumRootN(i);
            //Console.WriteLine("root {0} : {1} ", i, result);
        });


        labelTime.Text = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms";


        this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;

    }
```

This produces:
 [image]

I want to take advantage of the number of cores and logical processors on the CPU.  How can I do this in C# i.e. if a machie has more cores then I want to split the work up onto each core so a machine with more cores and logical procesors will run the test faster.

Comment: `Parallel.For` should already do something similar to what you're asking... what's not working with that?

Comment: Thanks for reply.  My solution works but I want to make sure I'm specifically giving a part of the work to each core etc.  I want to build a relaiable test tool that I can to use to 'benchmark' different types of processors.

Comment: IMO more suitable for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: So for example if I have 8 logical processors I want to split my task up into 8 and give each logical processor a task therefore reducing the overall time taken.

Answer (score 1):

If you're building a benchmark you should control threading tightly. Start N threads manually where N is `Environment.ProcessorCount`. Don't even use the `Task` facility because it gives you less fairness guarantees.

You might want to increase the thread priority to reduce context switching induced timing jitter.

Comment: If I start N threads then how can I guarantee that each thread will get run on each Processor???

Comment: The OS does that. Scheduling overheads are negligible if you match the number of cores with the same number of threads, and you don't have significant other activity going on in the system.